# Remove selected options from drop down and display the available options - select-form-control - Angular

Tags: html, angular

I need to remove the selected options from the drop-down and display only the available options in the subsequent drop-downs. The first time getAvailableLocationsList() is returning all the available options. Once the value is selected from the first drop-down, the second drop-down is showing the remaining options that aren't selected yet. But, when I go back to see the first drop-downs value, the option initially selected is not selected, as I'm removing the selected value from the list. The number of drop-downs and options would be dynamic, I would need to have the first drop-down showing all available options, and the consequent drop-downs to not have the already selected options.

HTML Code:

```
<div formArrayName="locationArray">
    <div *ngFor="let location of list.controls[index].get('locationArray').controls;let locationIndex=index">
        <div [formGroupName]="locationIndex">
            <select class="form-control" formControlName="location" id="{{'location'+index}}" (change)="getLocationName(index, locationIndex)">
                <option disabled value=""> Select</option>
                <option *ngFor="let item of getAvailableLocationsList(index, locationIndex)" ngDefaultControl [ngValue]="item.address">{{item.address}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Typescript code:

```
getAvailableLocationsList(index, locationIndex) {
    let locationList = []; // Array- from service;
    const list= <FormArray>this.form.get('list');
    const locationArray = 
    <FormArray>list.controls[index].get('locationArray')['controls'][locationIndex].get('location');
    const locationVal = locationArray.value;
    const selectedLoc = _.findWhere(locationList, { address: locationVal });
    if (!_.isUndefined(selectedLoc)) {
        locationList = _.filter(locationList, (eachLoc) => {
            return eachLoc.address.id!== selectedLoc.id;
        });
    }
    return locationList;
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

One Problem is that everything is set to constants for the information that you are pulling from on this list. Constants cannot be changed.

I would suggest placing the locations you are going to use in a temp array, then once the option is selected, in the function that is called, remove the option from that temp array. That way each time you go back to the drop down, it no longer has that option to provide:

Comment: thanks for pointing that one out. I tried changing the const to a temporary array. I’m able to filter out the options that are not selected. The problem I’m encountering is that list that is looping through - (locationList)is removing the selected option from the first drop down.

Comment: Suppose I have 2 drop downs and two locations. Drop down 1 initially displays two locations and we select location 1. Drop down 2 displays the remaining one location, i.e location 2 but when I get back to see drop down 1 I’m seeing location 2 instead of one.

Comment: so to make sure I have this correct.
1) You select location 1 from drop down 1

2) that leaves location 2 remaining in drop down 2

3) You do not select location 2 from drop down 2, 

4) You click drop down 1 again, and only location 2 is there?

Comment: If so that seams to be expected behavior. Given your code, as soon as an option is selected it is removed from the list, so depending on what is happening, you could select a drop down, select an option, then click the dropdown again, and the option will no longer be there.

Comment: I’ve selected drop down 1 with location 1. That leaves me with location 2 for drop down 2. We are good so far. Now, without clicking on drop down 1, I see the location 2 value being there already. I understand that it’s because I’ve removed the selected value from the list and the list is updated with the non-selected location. But I need to have drop down 1 with location 1 (selected option) and drop down 2 without the location 1. The location 1 is being removed. Can you please suggest how to handle this scenario?

Comment: The easiest solution for your needs is to have 2 arrays. One for drop down 1, and a second for drop down 2. When drop down 1 selects an option, that option is removed from drop down 2's array, not drop down 1. That way, you will still have the selected option for drop down 1, where it should show it's been selected, and drop down 2 will no longer have access to the already selected option.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I’m having a form array with select form controls. Not sure how I’d be able to achieve having two different arrays for the two drop downs with form controls. Can you help me with a pseudo code?

Comment: The number of locations and the number of drop downs would be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, my last comment was a bad solution. The reason why is because if you select the wrong option from drop down 1, then select a different option from drop down 1, you will now be missing 2 options from drop down 2 instead of just one. What you should do instead is the following:

disable the option from the list using only one array:
in your controller:

```
arrayOfLocationsForDropdowns = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
selectedOptionFromDropDownOne = selected location;
```

in your html:

drop down 1 :

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="location">
    <option *ngFor="let location of locationList" [value]="location">{{location}}</option>
</select>
```

** still use your filtering technique but don't take out the selected option, set that option equal to the variable selectedOptionFromDropDownOne instead

drop down 2:

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="location2">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let location of locationList" >
         <option *ngIf="location != selectedOptionFromDropDownOne" [value]="location">{{location}}</option>
    </ng-container>
</select>
```

This will allow you to use all of the data without taking any out and it will display all values in the second drop down list except for the option that was selected in the first drop down list.

To make this more dynamic make the variable selectedOptionFromDropDownOne an array and check the array for subsequent drop downs:

arrayOfSelectedOptionsFromPreviousChoices = []
then in the code for future selects:

change the ngIf from *ngIf="location != selectedOptionFromDropDownOne" to
*ngIf="!location in arrayOfSelectedOptionsFromPreviousChoices"

Comment: This is not working for me. It is removing the selected option from the same dropdown. I have added a question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63057648/remove-selected-option-from-drop-down-in-angular