# Remove selected option from drop down in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a button which adds more select drop downs when clicked. So I would like to remove the already selected options in these select boxes for preventing duplication.

The following code is used for the select drop down:

```
<select class="select form-control"
   formControlName="environment_id" (change)="onEnvChange($event.target.value)">
   <option selected="selected" disabled value="">Select Environment
   </option>
   <ng-container  *ngFor="let environment of environments">
      <option *ngIf="!selectedEnvironments.includes(environment.environment_id)"
      [value]="environment.environment_id">
      {{environment.environment_id}}</option>
   </ng-container>
</select>
```

and in the component I ave the following function for `change`

```
 public onEnvChange(selectedEnvironment)
 {
     this.selectedEnvironments.push(selectedEnvironment);
 }
```

Now when I select an option, that option itself gets removed from the dropdown. For example if I have options like `option1,option2,option3` etc, when I select `option1`, `option1` is getting removed from the dropdown. How to fix this and remove the option only for the next select dropdown ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56887985/how-to-remove-the-previously-selected-option-from-a-drop-down-menu-in-a-table/56891636#56891636

Answer (score 0):

You can try create two objects of environments and listen selection with valueChanges from formControl. After you get the selected environmentid and filter the other object without this id

Example

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.createForm();
    this.getEnvironments();
    this.environmentChanges()
  }

  createForm(){
      this.form = this.fb.group({
           'environment_id_1': [''],
           'environment_id_2' : ['']
})}

  getEnvironments(){
      const environments = [
      {  'environment_id': 1, 'environment': 'A'  },
      {  'environment_id': 2, 'environment': 'B'  },
      {  'environment_id': 3, 'environment': 'C'  },
      {  'environment_id': 4, 'environment': 'D'  }];
      this.environments1 = environments;
      this.environments2 = environments;}

  environmentChanges(){
     this.form.controls['environment_id_1'].valueChanges
             .subscribe((environment_id)=>{
             this.environments2 = this.environments1.filter((env)=> env.environment_id != environment_id)
})}

<form [formGroup]="form">
<div class="row">
    <select class="select form-control"   formControlName="environment_id_1">   
        <option value="">Select Environment 1 </option> 
        <option *ngFor="let environment of environments1"  [value]="environment.environment_id"> {{environment.environment}} </option> 
    </select>
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px;">
    <select class="select form-control"   formControlName="environment_id_2">   
        <option value="">Select Environment 2 </option> 
        <option *ngFor="let environment of environments2"  [value]="environment.environment_id"> {{environment.environment}} </option> 
    </select>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oefvo.png)